# Text messages sent via iMessage

Tags: ipad

Did a backup(not restore) of iPad and now my messages sent from iPad do not show up on iPhone - also messages sent from iPad show up as my email not my phone#

Answer (score 1):

Check the messages settings. It's in Settings>Messages. Under Send & Receive are the options to choose how you can be reached and how it starts new conversations.